# Validating a triangle in C

Tags: c

I'm new in C, so I try to create a program that calculate the area of triangle as a start.

Calculating the area is easy when the triangle exists, however the validation of straight line is working partially.

Example:

***A(0,-4) B(1,0) C(4,12)*** does not produce straight line error.

but
***A(4,12) B(1,0) C(0,-4)*** produce straight line error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double square(double num){
    return (num*num);
}

int main()
{

    double x[5],y[5],a,b,c,angle,area;

    printf("Hello there! Calculating the area of triangle.\n");

    printf("Enter a coordinate A :\n");
    scanf("%lf,%lf",&x[0],&y[0]);

    printf("Enter another coordinate B :\n");
    scanf("%lf,%lf",&x[1],&y[1]);

    printf("Enter another coordinate C :\n");
    scanf("%lf,%lf",&x[2],&y[2]);

    // AB as base (a) , c is opposite side 

    a = sqrt( square((x[0]-x[1])) + square((y[0]-y[1])) );
    b = sqrt( square((x[0]-x[2])) + square((y[0]-y[2])) );
    c = sqrt( square(x[1]-x[2]) + square((y[1]-y[2])) );

    double num = (square(a)+square(b)-square(c))/(2*a*b);
    angle = acos(num);
    area = .5*a*b*sin(angle);

   //printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf \n",a,b,c,num,angle);

    if (num == 1 || num ==-1){
        printf("That's a straight line.");
    }else{
        printf("Area of triangle is %lf\n",area);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Three collinear points do form a degenerate triangle with area zero; IAC, you may want to look at [Is Floating Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: sometimes it does return 0 and nan. ok i'll into that

Comment: You can get a more accurate length with `a = sqrt( square((x[0]-x[1])) + square((y[0]-y[1])) );` --> `a = hypot(x[0]-x[1],  y[0]-y[1]);`.  Easier to read too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a different test, and perhaps a different area formula. If you use Heron's formula, then once you have the lengths of the sides *a*, *b*, and *c*, you can compute:

```
double p = (a + b + c)/2;
double area = sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
```

You can detect if the triangle is valid by checking that *p* is greater than each of the sides.

```
double p = (a + b + c)/2;
if ((p > a) && (p > b) && (p > c)) {
    double area = sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
    printf("Area of triangle is %lf\n", area);
} else {
    printf("I don't consider that a triangle.\n");
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLfb5swEH7nr7hlSmZ3pgPU7SVrJZLXak@b1CnLg3FssEQMw44abeq/PnbGJKDWEue7737ynUVcCtH377UR9ekg4at1B93cVg/RBB25qzwSHZpTUUtom@cMyGicKfyFTrpTZ@B8c17DyzWulqZ01TXyaZftGYzGTzQwMwI8Y7b93Tnia5OnXbKHGGMSjPkII5YGLN1Tuo6wizYOjlwbQqNQR1S8g@KkdtnnL/v1AD1XGpsRVUpnCboYWP1HNsrrFA38WUPh3T18@/H4eJnHn3HMfJh5M8gtyvXrAM6gYCDe4C0D3kk@4dYKblSYYUGWKJeKwhtlwa4Z41nlSAPzV@qvTbA2wdoGa@tZmXpxuB/JJzlOP/MUk2eDfzTziMmzZZDPPC16CMc9FPgJ@imbXFoBIS08AKewWsGgFpMq6JzSYTLkBMuFVd@QNubUy2KQgs66Dp073LEii9xnNQpcp7kpkV1tYVmrX2YRWJ6lvYCsrXzV9VLne8XdB4v0WNdxXVYOam3kLdaZV4gmOb7MBN9b35OExXe4qZQlKO9YmtEoXBcsBPwTqual7eP6@B8)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is `double num = (square(a)+square(b)-square(c))/(2*a*b);` gets evaluated to a number slightly larger than 1 in some cases. This can happen with floating point computations. In your case you can safely add `if (num > 1) num = 1;` after that line since cosine equation always will give you a value larger than 0 and less than 1 for triangles.

However there's a problem if two points overlap and `a` or `b` becomes zero. You will have to check for that and handle it as a special case if such input is expected by your code. (If two points overlap then they are collinear anyways. You can check the overlap by checking if any of `a,b,c` are zero)

Comment: I suspect "slightly less than -1" can occur too.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Actually no. For any given triangle, `a+b > c` holds. Therefore `square(a)+square(b)-square(c)` will always be positive. The edge cases are `a+b = c` where the points are in a line. In that case the angle will be zero. When two points overlap, there's a problem since a division by zero can occur.

Comment: That is a good geometry explanation, yet we are using FP math with all its impreciseness, sub-normals, infinities and rounding as compared to pure math.  I see little loss insuring `fabs(num <= 1.0)` vs risking `NaN`.  Note: `2*a*b` may be zero, even if `a` and `b` are not.

Comment: I agree with you. Since OP is a beginner, I didn't mention anything about the 
floating point comparisons. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850663/comparing-same-float-values-in-c) if OP needs more insight on that. I acually use the following function in C++ for FP comparisons
`template<typename T> inline bool isAproxEqual(T x, T y) { return std::fabs(x - y) <= std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon(); }`

Comment: `std::fabs(x - y) <= std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()` takes the floating out of floating point.  It does not fail when `x,y` are large and consecutive `double`s and always passes when `x,y` have small magnitudes.  Such a test is only useful for a narrow mid-range of `double`.

Comment: thanks for the link, yes I have read that num might slightly bigger/lower than 1 and -1. i assume the coordinates no precise than 5 dp and round the num to 5dp to match 1/-1 and it works. i did also try using fabs(x-1.0f) < 0.1e-8 and it works too