# Floating point does not print accurately

Tags: c, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point issue in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916439/floating-point-issue-in-c)

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
        int a,b;
        float f;
        scanf("%2d%3d%4f",&a,&b,&f);
        printf("%d %d %f",a,b,f);
}
```

When i run this program and input 2 4 56.8 ,it gives output 2 4 56.799999.....but I would expect 2 4 56.8....why is it so???

Comment: doesn't `printf` `"%f"` expect a `double`?

Comment: I think it will work both for float and double....

Comment: @FlorianSowade, yes but float arguments get promoted to double for functions without prototypes and variadic arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is correct.  Floating point numbers are approximations.  Just as 0.33333333 is an approximation to 1/3, 56.7999999 is an approximation for 56.8.  There is no exact floating point representation for 0.1.

See some of what has been written:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html
- http://www.hack3r.com/forum-topic/what-every-programmer-should-know-about-floating-point-arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

56.8 is not exactly-representable in the floating-point format used by your C compiler.
See *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic* (1991) by David Goldberg.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with floating point inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

All floating point numbers cannot be stored as its exact value, as the continuous space of the floating point number domain is mapped into a discrete levels. For example the floating point number can be stored in the [IEEE754](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) single precision format. It stores the floating number in three parts in 32 bits of memory. Assume that `[a, b]` are the two closest floating point numbers that can be represented exactly with IEEE754 format, but we will have infinite number of floating point numbers in between `a` and `b`, in that case these numbers will be approximated with either `a` or `b`. This induces the imprecision you are experiencing.

The number is stored in normalized format, although some very small number can be stored in unnormalized format. Just have a look at the documents.

For example in your case 56.8 IEEE754 single point precision representation will be as follows:

- sign: 0  (1 bit)
- biased exponent: 10000100 (8 bits)
- mantissa: 11000110011001100110011 (23 bits)

Now, if you convert back this number into decimal then you get

- sign is 0 ie the value is positive
- 10000100 = 132 bias amount 127 therefore exponent = 132 - 127 = 5
- mantissa with hidden bit 1.11000110011001100110011
- after adjusting decimal point with exponent (move 5 places right): 111000.110011001100110011

  - The integer part  :  111000 = 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 = 56
  - The fraction part : .110011001100110011 = 2^-1 + 2^-2 + 2^-5 + 2^-6 + 2^-9 + 2^-10 + 2^-13 + 2^-14 + 2^-17 + 2^-18 = 0.799999237

Therefore when you retrieve the value from the IEEE754 single precision format it becomes: 56.799999237 where you have stored 56.8

You can play with IEEE754 representation here: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html