# Assertion error

Tags: java

I have written(shown below) a method getCelsius to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius but when I run the program it shows me an assertion error.

Code:

Method in class Temperature:

```
public double getCelsius() {

        double c = 0;
        c =  ((this.temp_value - 32) * (5 / 9));
        return c;
    }
```

and here is the method call in class TestTemperature, which gives me an assertion error:

```
Temperature t = new Temperature(212.0, "F");

assert t.getCelsius() == 100.0;  // < error in this line
```

Help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange output in comparision of float with float literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparision-of-float-with-float-literal)

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple problems: firstly, the `5 / 9` part is using integer division, so it will return 0 all the time. You need to change `5 / 9` to `5f / 9` or something similar.

Secondly `(212f - 32) * (5f / 9)` is not exactly `100.0`: it's hard to do floating point comparison because not all values that you can write in Java are exactly representable in IEEE754 floating point numbers. So you should compare the two numbers like this: `assert Math.abs(t.getCelsius() - expected) < 0.000001` or some other desired maximum difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account precision/representation. i.e. perform your test like so:

```
assert Abs(t.getCelsius() - 100.0) < epsilon;
```

where epsilon is your tolerance (say, 0.000001)

You should very rarely use exact equality comparison when dealing with floating point quantities; use a tolerance instead.

Also, write your conversion factor to use floating point arithmetic:

```
    c =  ((this.temp_value - 32) * (5.0 / 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

well, if you want it that way

```
// will return "exact" value if input is 212.0 or 32.0
double f2c(double f)
{
    return  (f-32.0)/(212.0-32.0) * 100.0;
}

assert f2c(212.0)==100.0 ;  // true!
assert f2c( 32.0)==  0.0 ;  // true!
```

more generally, if we have two end points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`, this linear interpolation

```
y = (x-x2)/(x1-x2) * y1 + (x-x1)/(x2-x1) * y2
```

will evaluate "exactly" to `y1` at `x=x1`, and `y2` at `x=x2`. Valid for `double/float/int/short/byte`