# Why comparing double and float leads to unexpected result?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strange output in comparision of float with float literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparision-of-float-with-float-literal)

```
float f = 1.1;
double d = 1.1;
if(f == d) // returns false!
```

Why is it so?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/test/doc/components/test_tools/floating_point_comparison.html

Comment: Google "what every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic" for some interesting reads.

Comment: Never use `==` for comparing floating-point values.  Instead use something more along the lines of `if (abs(f - d) < 0.001)`.

Comment: @ Bart: Its actually int the C++ tag section => http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info : Just scroll down. You will se the tag [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @aroth bad idea: what if f is 0.0001 and d is 0.00001 ?

Comment: @stijn - That was just an example.  Obviously if you are working with very small numbers (or anything else that requires very high precision) then you might want to use a different approach.  Such as not using `double` and `float` at all and finding a good arbitrary-precision arithmetic library instead.

Comment: @Martin Ah, good to know. Won't be the last time this kind of question comes up. Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

The important factors under consideration with `float` or `double` numbers are:
**Precision** & **Rounding**

---

**Precision:**
*The precision of a floating point number is how many digits it can represent without losing any information it contains.*

Consider the fraction `1/3`. The decimal representation of this number is `0.33333333333333…` with 3′s going out to infinity. An infinite length number would require infinite memory to be depicted with exact precision, but `float` or `double` data types typically only have `4` or `8` bytes. Thus Floating point & double numbers can only store a certain number of digits, and the rest are bound to get lost. Thus, there is no definite accurate way of representing float or double numbers with numbers that require more precision than the variables can hold.

---

**Rounding:**
There is a non-obvious differences between `binary` and `decimal (base 10)` numbers.
Consider the fraction `1/10`. In `decimal`, this can be easily represented as `0.1`, and `0.1` can be thought of as an easily representable number. However, in binary, `0.1` is represented by the infinite sequence: `0.00011001100110011…`

An example:

```
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << setprecision(17);
    double dValue = 0.1;
    cout << dValue << endl;
}
```

This output is:

```
0.10000000000000001
```

And not

```
0.1.
```

This is because the double had to truncate the approximation due to it’s limited memory, which results in a number that is not exactly `0.1`. Such an scenario is called a **Rounding error**.

---

Whenever comparing two close float and double numbers such rounding errors kick in and eventually the comparison yields incorrect results and this is the reason you should never compare floating point numbers or double using `==`.

The best you can do is to take their difference and check if it is less than an epsilon.

```
abs(x - y) < epsilon
```

Comment: This is a valid answer, +1 to offset downvotes.
It leaves information to be desired, but is valid all the same.

Comment: They can be represented fairly accurately, just not absolutely precisely in all cases.

Comment: @Als: This information is much better.  Converted my down-vote to an upvote, and removed my dissenting comments :)

Answer (score 9):

Try running this code, the results will make the reason obvious.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << (double)1.1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << (float)1.1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << (double)((float)1.1) << std::endl;
}
```

The output:

```
1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
1.10000002384185791015625
1.10000002384185791015625
```

Neither `float` nor `double` can represent 1.1 accurately. When you try to do the comparison the float number is implicitly upconverted to a double. The double data type can accurately represent the contents of the float, so the comparison yields false.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you shouldn't compare floats to floats, doubles to doubles, or floats to doubles using `==`.

The best practice is to subtract them, and check if the absolute value of the difference is less than a small epsilon.

```
if(std::fabs(f - d) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon())
{
    // ...
}
```

One reason is because floating point numbers are (more or less) binary fractions, and can only approximate many decimal numbers.  Many decimal numbers must necessarily be converted to repeating binary "decimals", or irrational numbers.  This will introduce a rounding error.

[From wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point):

> For instance, 1/5 cannot be represented exactly as a floating point number using a binary base but can be represented exactly using a decimal base.

In your particular case, a float and double will have different rounding for the irrational/repeating fraction that must be used to represent `1.1` in binary.  You will be hard pressed to get them to be "equal" after their corresponding conversions have introduced different levels of rounding error.

The code I gave above solves this by simply checking if the values are within a very short delta.  Your comparison changes from "are these values equal?" to "are these values within a small margin of error from each other?"

Also, see this question: [What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

There are also a lot of other oddities about floating point numbers that break a simple equality comparison.  Check this article for a description of some of them:

http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Comment: The ε-neighbourhood is usually _not_ the best practice, but rather a lazy workaround. Most often you do not really want `==` anyway, but `<=` or `>=`, and just think you need `==` because that happens to work fine for integers since the case `>` is never reached with these. — Also, sometimes you _do_ in fact want `==` for floats, though this occurs rather seldom.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: This is contrary to most of the articles I've read.  Can you elaborate on these cases?  Maybe add your own answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The IEEE 754 32-bit `float` can store: `1.1000000238...`
The IEEE 754 64-bit `double` can store: `1.1000000000000000888...`

See why they're not "equal"?

---

In IEEE 754, fractions are stored in powers of 2:

```
2^(-1), 2^(-2), 2^(-3), ...
1/2,    1/4,    1/8,    ...
```

Now we need a way to represent `0.1`. This is (a simplified version of) the 32-bit IEEE 754 representation (float):

```
2^(-4) + 2^(-5) + 2^(-8) + 2^(-9) + 2^(-12) + 2^(-13) + ... + 2^(-24) + 2^(-25) + 2^(-27)
00011001100110011001101
1.10000002384185791015625
```

With 64-bit `double`, it's even more accurate. It doesn't stop at `2^(-25)`, it keeps going for about twice as much. (`2^(-48) + 2^(-49) + 2^(-51)`, maybe?)

---

> **Resources**
>
> [IEEE 754 Converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html) (32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Floats and doubles are stored in a binary format that can not represent every number exactly (it's impossible to represent the infinitely many possible different numbers in a finite space).

As a result they do rounding. Float has to round more than double, because it is smaller, so 1.1 rounded to the nearest valid Float is different to 1.1 rounded to the nearest valud Double.

To see what numbers are valid floats and doubles see [Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)