# different values of std::floor function for arguments with same value but different types

Tags: c++, logging, floor

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  const long double be2 = std::log(2);
  cout << std::log(8.0) / be2 << ", " << std::floor(std::log(8.0) / be2)
      << endl;

  cout << std::log(8.0L) / be2 << ", " << std::floor(std::log(8.0L) / be2)
      << endl;
}
```

Outputs

```
  3, 2
  3, 3
```

Why does the output differ? What am I missing here?

Also here is the link to codepad: http://codepad.org/baLtYrmy

And I'm using gcc 4.5 on linux, if that's important.

Comment: FYI, Visual C++ 2010 gives: 3, 3 and 3, 3. BTW, I needed to do "std::log(2.0)" instead of "std::log(2)" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @Branko : VC++ treats `long double` as a synonym for `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I add this:

```
cout.precision(40);
```

I get this output:

```
2.999999999999999839754918906642444653698, 2
3.00000000000000010039712117215771058909, 3
```

You're printing two values that are very close to, but not exactly equal to, 3.0.  It's the nature of `std::floor` that its results can differ for values that are very close together (mathematically, it's a discontinuous function).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  const long double be2 = std::log(2);

  cout << setprecision (50)<<std::log(8.0)<<"\n";
  cout << setprecision (50)<<std::log(8.0L)<<"\n";
  cout << setprecision (50)<<std::log(8.0) / be2 << ", " << std::floor(std::log(8.0) / be2)
       << endl;
  cout << setprecision (50)<< std::log(8.0L) / be2 << ", " << std::floor(std::log(8.0L) / be2)
       << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
2.0794415416798357476579894864698871970176696777344
2.0794415416798359282860714225549259026593063026667
2.9999999999999998397549189066424446536984760314226, 2
3.0000000000000001003971211721577105890901293605566, 3
```

If you check the output **[here](http://codepad.org/9mLnBJL6)**, you will notice that there is a slight difference in the precision of the two outputs. These roundoff errors usually kick in on operations on float & double here while performing `floor()` and the results that appear are not what one feels they should be.

It is important to remember two attributes **Precision** & **Rounding** when you are working with float or double numbers.

You might want to read more about it in my answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722293/why-comparing-double-and-float-leads-to-unexpected-result/6722297#6722297)**, the same reasoning applies here as well.

Comment: I see no difference in the output

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what Als is saying-

In the first case you are dividing an 8-byte double precision value by a 16-byte long double.  In the second case you are dividing a 16-byte long double by a 16-byte long double.  This results in a very small roundoff error which can be seen here:

```
cout << std::setprecision(20) << (std::log(8.0) / be2) << std::endl;
cout << std::setprecision(20) << (std::log(8.0L) / be2) << std::endl;
```

which yields:

```
2.9999999999999998398
3.0000000000000001004
```

Edit to say: in this case, sizeof is your friend (To see the difference in precision):

```
sizeof(std::log(8.0));  // 8
sizeof(std::log(8.0L)); // 16
sizeof(be2);            // 16
```

Comment: 8-bit doubles? Is that a typo, perhaps?