# Float constant value different depending upon how it's declared C++ (Xcode IDE)

Tags: c++, xcode, floating-point, constants

I'm working through C++ Primer Plus, using Xcode as my IDE and one of the exercises calls for assigning the value 0.0254 to a symbolic constant (converting inches to meters). The problem is, when I declare the constant I'm getting a value of 0.0253999997. I'm declaring the constant as seen below.

```
#include <iostream>
const float METERS_PER_INCH = .0254;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're starting with C++, I recommend [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642). Now let me see if I can answer your question :)

Comment: I'll try 0.0254f, thanks. Also, this exercise I'm having the issue with is from the C++ Primer, Chapter 3, exercise #2 (converting height in inches to meters).

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange output in comparision of float with float literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparision-of-float-with-float-literal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry your mac is OK.

Problem is that computers can't accurately represent floats and doubles so this is what you are seeing there.

[Why comparing double and float leads to unexpected result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722293/why-comparing-double-and-float-leads-to-unexpected-result)

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

[strange output in comparison of float with float literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparision-of-float-with-float-literal)

Google is your friend!

Comment: I had actually found the stack posting but now I understand a little more about it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue of rounding error due to floats storing numbers in a base 2 number system(think about how we cannot write 1/3 without rounding in our base 10 number system). It results in small rounding errors like the ones you are seeing when you store non-base 2 numbers.

The solution is to use integers or a bignum library(I suggest the [GNU
Multiple Precision library](http://gmplib.org/) ). A bignumber library uses integers to store arbitrary precision numbers exactly.