# Are 3.5 and 3.5f the same in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strange output in comparision of float with float literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparision-of-float-with-float-literal)
>   [Why comparing double and float leads to unexpected result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722293/why-comparing-double-and-float-leads-to-unexpected-result)

In following code I was expecting answer to be "Not equal", because by default the `3.5`  should be `double` in C++, but the result was "equal".

What is difference in declaring `float a=3.5f` and `float a=3.5`?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a=3.5;
    if(a==3.5)  
        cout<<"equal"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Not equal"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try creating a double and float which are both equal to 1.0/3.0 and then seee if they are equal.  You'll find that they're not.

Comment: Yes Benj I got your point. What you mean to say this those are not equal because of precision.

Comment: when comparing floating point values for equality I always use : fabs(v1-v2)<EPSILON where EPSILON is small floating point value like 0.00001

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

The type of`3.5` is `double` whereas the type of `3.5f` is float. So they are **not guaranteed to be equal** in values.

```
#include<iostream>

void f(double) { std::cout << "it is double" << std::endl; }
void f(float)  { std::cout << "it is float" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
   f(3.5);
   f(3.5f);
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/V8diH):

```
it is double
it is float
```

Comment: `3.5 == 3.5f` *is* guaranteed by IEEE754, which most "normal" systems use these days.

Comment: But 10.0f/3.0f is not guaranteed to be equal to 10.0/3.0. He happened to pick an exact number.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Yes, *"3.5 == 3.5f is guaranteed by IEEE754"*, but it is not guaranteed by C++, as an implementation can choose *any* floating-point format.

Answer (score 2):

Float are not an exact number. Comparing them with == is never an good idea.
Here is why: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Floats _do_ represent exact numbers; however, there are many numbers which cannot be represented by any float.