# Passing std::vector of float values to a function changes values a bit

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a very simple little function that is supposed to verify the values in the passed `vector`:

```
bool Verify( std::vector<std::pair<float, float>> const & source) {
    // The lookup table must be changing linearly on input
    float delta_x{};
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < source.size(); i++) {
        auto input_delta = std::abs(source[i].first - source[i-1].first);
        if (i == 1) {
            delta_x = input_delta;
        } else {
            std::cout << "LUT"
              << "Expected step: '" << std::setprecision(10) << delta_x << "'."
              << " measured step[" << i << "]: '"
              << std::setprecision(10) << input_delta << "'"
              << (input_delta-delta_x)
              << ":" << source[i].first << "-" << source[i-1].first << std::endl;
        if (delta_x != input_delta) {
            return false;
        }
     }
  }

  return true;
}
```

It seems fairly straightforward. However, it fails. When I pass a simple vector like this:

```
    std::vector<std::pair<float, float>>kDecodeLut{
  {  -1.326, 101.3974},
  {   6.174, 96.0049 },
  {  13.674, 91.5644 },
  {  21.174, 87.5549 },
  {  28.674, 83.7873 },
  {  36.174, 80.1683 },
  {  43.674, 76.6441 },
  {  51.174, 73.1802 },
  {  58.674, 69.7524 }};
```

The values that the `Verify` method sees are not exactly the same as in the vector. Here is the printout:

```
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[2]: '7.5'0:13.67399979-6.173999786
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[3]: '7.5'0:21.17399979-13.67399979
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[4]: '7.5'0:28.67399979-21.17399979
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[5]: '7.5'0:36.17399979-28.67399979
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[6]: '7.5'0:43.67399979-36.17399979
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[7]: '7.5'0:51.17399979-43.67399979
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[8]: '7.5'0:58.67399979-51.17399979
```

It appears as if there was some number conversion from the original `kDecodeLut` vector to the internal variable inside `Verify`.

Was there really some sort of conversion? I didn't intend for the `kDecodeLut` vector to be copied or modified in any form.
What else can explain this behavior?

---

**Edit**:
I've added the code to print the values *before* calling `Verify` and they come out as expected.

```
 for (unsigned i = 1; i < kTiltWingDecodeLut.size(); i++) {
  std::cout << "LUT"
            << ":" << kTiltWingDecodeLut[i].first << "-" << kTiltWingDecodeLut[i-1].first << std::endl;
}
Verify(kTiltWingDecodeLut);
```

Here is the output

```
LUT:6.174--1.326
LUT:13.674-6.174
LUT:21.174-13.674
LUT:28.674-21.174
LUT:36.174-28.674
LUT:43.674-36.174
LUT:51.174-43.674
LUT:58.674-51.174
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[2]: '7.5'0:13.67399979-6.173999786
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[3]: '7.5'0:21.17399979-13.67399979
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[4]: '7.5'0:28.67399979-21.17399979
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[5]: '7.5'0:36.17399979-28.67399979
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[6]: '7.5'0:43.67399979-36.17399979
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[7]: '7.5'0:51.17399979-43.67399979
LUTExpected step: '7.5'. measured step[8]: '7.5'0:58.67399979-51.17399979
```

Comment: Why do you think that there was a number conversion? Because the output is something like `6.173999786` instead of `6.174`? That is because a float number can not store numbers of arbitrary precision and the actual number that it holds is often slightly off. When you create the vector, the first number is stored from the beginning, not `6.174`.

Comment: 6.174 is likely stored as 6.173999786 and I would argue that Verify actually does get the exact same numbers as you passe in.

Comment: I have a bit of code that prints the values _before_ `Verify` and the numbers come out as `6.174`.

Comment: Show us that code then. We need a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing double values in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278523/comparing-double-values-in-c)

Comment: Please read about [mcve] again and try to come up with something that is in fact one. All words in the title are significant so pay attention to what they mean.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of rounding. As you can see on [this page](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html), 6.174, when converted to 32-bit floating point is more like 6.1739998. The actual representation is explained on that page: 2^2*1.5434999 (1.10001011001000101101000 in binary.) The 64-bit floating point value uses the **additional** binary bits of 01110010101100000010000011001 in the multiplier after those of the 32-bit value.

If you use the same `setprecision(10)` to print the before values, you will see the same numbers.

Comment: You are right, @Khouri. I did add `std::setprecision(10)` to before code and it prints the same values.

Comment: BTW, as defined by `FLT_DIG` in `<float.h>`, a 32-bit floating point value is only good for 6 digits. `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` is defined as 9, meaning it only takes 9 decimal digits to uniquely identify a 32-bit floating point value. This is a bit confusing with `setprecision` because **digits**, which starts at the first digit, is not the same as **decimal place values**, which starts at the decimal place.