# Double multiplication differs between compile time and runtime in 32 bit platform

Tags: c, double, 32bit-64bit

I'm compiling and running the following program in 32 and 64 bit platforms:

```
int main()
{
  double y = 8.34214e08;
  double z = 1.25823e45;

  return y * z == 8.34214e08 * 1.25823e45;
}
```

While in 64bit the result is the expected (the values are the same and the exit code is non-zero) in 32bit seems there is a little difference between the value calculated at compile time, the right hand side of the comparison, and the left side computed at runtime.

Is this a bug in the compiler or there is a logical explanation?

EDIT: this is different from [Why comparing double and float leads to unexpected result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722293) because here all the values are double.

Comment: @waj: I didn't downvote your question.  It's a fine question.

Comment: @SteveSummit ok, sorry about that then, I got the downvote at the same time you replied and StackOverflow doesn't show who voted. Anyway, I can live with it but I really need to know the reasons, that's why I'm sending a question here in the first place.

Comment: @Giorgi: in that question there is a difference because the variable is declared as "float" and the literals are "double". Here all the values are double.

Comment: @waj with gcc 5.1 it gives 1 on amd64 as well as armv7h (ARM 32 bit).. What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc appears to optimize the program down to `return 1` with any optimization level above `-O0`.

Comment: You have compared floats for equality. Go forth and sin no more.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: :) I know, I'm not doing float equality on a real program. I just wanted to understand why the result is different when compiling and running on the same machine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IEEE-754 allows intermediate computations to be done in a greater precision (emphasis mine).

> (IEEE-754:2008) "A language standard should also define, and require   implementations to provide, attributes that allow and disallow  value-changing optimizations, separately or collectively, for a block. These optimizations might include, but are not limited to: [...] **Use of wider intermediate results in expression evaluation**."

In your case for example on a IA-32, the double values could be stored in the x87 FPU registers with greater precision (80-bit instead of 64). So you are actually comparing a multiplication done on double precision with a multiplication done on double-extended precision.

For example, on x64 where the result is `1` (the x87 FPU is not used as SSE is used instead), adding `gcc` option `-mfpmath=387` to use the x87 makes the result change to `0` on my machine.

And if you wonder if that is also allowed by C, it is:

> (C99, 6.3.1.p8) "The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type;"

Comment: Good explanation about wider intermediate results.

Answer (score 11):

In general, *never* do [equality checks with floating point numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm). You need to check whether the result you want differs from the result you get by less than a pre-set precision.

What is happening here is in all likelihood due to the multiplication being run on two different "platforms": once by your code, and once by the compiler, which may have a different precision. This happens with [most](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.2/g77/Floating_002dpoint-precision.html) [compilers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx).

Your program would *probably* work if you compiled it with **the same options that were used to compile the compiler** (supposing the compiler was compiled by itself). But that would not mean you would get the *correct* result; you would be getting the same precision error the compiler is getting.

(Also, I'm assuming that the compiler performs a straight multiplication *and* the parsing code recognizing floats does not enter into the equation. This might well be wishful thinking on my part).

## Testing

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-suse-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,obj-c++,java,ada --enable-checking=release --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --enable-ssp --disable-libssp --disable-plugin --with-bugurl=http://bugs.opensuse.org/ --with-pkgversion='SUSE Linux' --disable-libgcj --disable-libmudflap --with-slibdir=/lib64 --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=new --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-linker-build-id --enable-linux-futex --program-suffix=-4.8 --without-system-libunwind --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --build=x86_64-suse-linux --host=x86_64-suse-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 20141208 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 218481] (SUSE Linux)



#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double y = 8.34214e08;
  double z = 1.25823e45;

 return  printf("%s\n", y * z == 8.34214e08 * 1.25823e45 ? "Equal" : "NOT equal!");
}
```

Forcing -O0 to avoid the compiler from optimizing out the whole code (thanks @markgz!), we get

$ gcc -m32 -O0 -o float float.c && ./float
 NOT equal!
 $ gcc -m32 -frounding-math -O0 -o float float.c && ./float
 Equal

For the record, since you got there before me :-),

> -frounding-math
>
> Disable transformations and optimizations that assume default floating-point rounding behavior.  This is round-to-zero for all
>   floating point to integer conversions, and round-to-nearest for all
>   other arithmetic truncations.  This option should be specified for
>   programs that change the FP rounding mode dynamically, or that may be
>   executed with a non-default rounding mode. This option disables
>   constant folding of floating-point expressions at compile time **(which
>   may be affected by rounding mode)** and arithmetic transformations that
>   are unsafe in the presence of sign-dependent rounding modes.
>
> The default is -fno-rounding-math.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that I'm running the compilation and execution on the same machine each time. I totally agree that in general, equality should not be used for floating points.

Comment: I was about to answer something like this, but what really puzzles me, is the difference between compile-time and run-time calculation. I would have thought GCC did the compile-time calculation using the same precision / settings as in the run-time calculation or whatever, but somehow the result differs :) I'm as puzzled as @waj

Comment: I remember getting weird results with `gcc` some years back, due to some math "optimization" I had overlooked. There are several "floating point" standards and gcc, for one, supports *all* of them. Of course gcc ran with only one - the one with which itself was compiled. And I might have been a bit, er, too free when building the toolchain. My professor was *really* not amused :-)

Comment: You're right, I compiled again with -frounding-math and the results are now the same. I found more info here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath#Note_on_built-in_math_functions

Comment: Gcc fully optimizes the calculation down to 'true' with any optimization level above -O0 (due to constant folding).  One would need to fool gcc's constant folding optimization with a more complex program to test the OP's original question.

Answer (score 5):

Floating point calculations done at compile time often occur at a higher precision than `double` uses at run time.  Also C may perform run-time intermediate `double` calculations at the higher `long double` precision.  Either explain your inequality.  See `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` for details.

```
  volatile double y = 8.34214e08;
  volatile double z = 1.25823e45;
  volatile double yz = 8.34214e08 * 1.25823e45;
  printf("%.20e\n", y);
  printf("%.20e\n", z);
  printf("%.20e\n", yz);
  printf("%.20Le\n", (long double) y*z);
  printf("%.20Le\n", (long double) 8.34214e08 * 1.25823e45);

8.34214000000000000000e+08
1.25822999999999992531e+45
// 3 different products!
1.04963308121999993395e+54
1.04963308121999993769e+54
1.04963308122000000000e+54
```

Your results may slightly differ.