# C/C++ Arithmetic expression with double numbers - strange results - translating in java

Tags: java, c++, c, double, arithmetic-expressions

FIRST PROBLEM

In C code I have this expression:

```
double completeExpression  = x1 - h*exp(-lambda*t);
```

I have split it in two operations:

```
double value = h*exp(-lambda*t);
double subtraction = x1 - value;
```

The problem is that subtraction is different from completeExpression.
What's the matter?

I have reproduced a strange results in my code with this lines:

```
const double TOLERANCE = 1e-16;
double h = 0.51152525298500628;
double lambda =0.99999999999999978;
double t=0.1;
double x1 =0.4628471891711442 ;

double completeExpression  = x1 - h*exp(-lambda*t);
double value = h*exp(-lambda*t);
double subtraction = x1 - value;

printf("x1 = %1.4e & value = %1.4e",x1,value);
printf("\ncompleteExpression = %1.4e",completeExpression);
printf("\nsubtraction = %1.4e",subtraction);
```

Results:

```
x1 = 4.6285e-001 & value = 4.6285e-001
completeExpression = 8.2779e-017
subtraction = 5.5511e-017
```

---

SECOND PROBLEM:

I have to translate the completeExpression in Java, and I have returned always the bad result (subtraction) and not completeExpression value:

Code:

```
 static double TOLERANCE = 1e-16;
   public static void main() {

        double h = 0.51152525298500628;
        double lambda =0.99999999999999978;
        double t=0.1;
        double x1 =0.4628471891711442 ;

        double completeExpression  = x1 - h*Math.exp(-lambda*t);
        double value = h*Math.exp(-lambda*t);
        double subtraction = x1 - value;

        System.out.println( "x1 = " + String.format("%1.4e", value) + "& value = " + String.format("%1.4e",x1) );
        System.out.println("\ncompleteExpression = " + String.format("%1.4e",completeExpression));
        System.out.println("\nsubtraction = " + String.format("%1.4e",subtraction));
```

---

```
#gcc --version

My Gcc Version:
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418209/double-multiplication-differs-between-compile-time-and-runtime-in-32-bit-platfor

Comment: Looks like a very common computational margin when dealing with non-integers

Comment: Floating point calculations are inexact; consequently, relying on exact results (e.g. testing of two numbers are inequal) is a bad idea. If you increase the precision in your `printf`s, you should be able to see the difference there too.

Comment: I [can't reproduce it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9eeafaede88116fb), which compiler are you using?

Comment: Try representing the mathematically exact real value of `1 / 7` with only 16 fractional decimal digits.

Comment: @alain see my answer...I write here. thanks

Comment: After changing the check to `Math.abs(...) > TOLERANCE`, it [works with java too](http://ideone.com/UNKsIJ)

Comment: @alain I don't understand why in C code completeExpression = 8.2779e-017
and subtraction = 5.5511e-017

Comment: But how do you get these numbers? Both the C and Java examples produce the exact same numbers.

Comment: @alain With my notebook and gcc I have these 2 different result 8.2779e-017 & 5.5511e-017.
If I code it in java I have always 5.5511e-017

Comment: Ok, that's really strange. However: 5.5511e-17 is the correct result, and since you are translating it to Java, and Java produces the correct result, it should be no problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point numbers (unlike integers) are almost never *exactly* the same. The reason is in the way they are stored (with the mantissa and the exponent).

In the end you can never be sure that the two floating-point numbers are the same after performing the "same" operations on them. And more to the point - the `if(subtraction!=completeExpression)` is generally invalid. Instead you should be looking for a "close match":

```
if( abs(subtraction - completeExpression) < TOLERANCE )
```

where `TOLERANCE` is some constant you have, like `const double TOLERANCE = 1e-16;`

For more information on why are the floating-point numbers "approximate" you can read the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) on `Floating point`. But the basic reason is that the range of numbers represented by the floating-point values is far larger than the number of digits that can be encoded into a given space.

A 32-bit integer can encode values from -2GB to +2GB but a 32-bit float's range is all the way from -3.4e38 to +3.4e38. That is a range difference of over 20 digits!

For a 64-bit values the range difference is even bigger and is almost 300 digits.

That extended range comes at a price - a portion of that 32 or 64 bit space is used to represent the "precision" digits (in binary, not in decimal) and the number of those is what is limiting the final precision of your floating-point numbers.

Generally speaking two numbers `123e456` and `1.23e458` (when represented in floating-point IEEE 754 binary format) are still going to be different, even though **mathematically** they are absolutely equal.

Comment: The issue is not the number of decimal places that can by the combination of the mantissa and exponent, but the the number that can be represent by the mantissa alone.  The numbers in the OP's original post (except 0.1) all looks as though they be inexactly represented.

Comment: I'll re-write my answer to make this point more clear (I agree - the mantissa is what limits the precision)

Comment: @YePhlcK thanks for the suggestion, I edited the code. Unfortunately the problem is always true

Comment: @michele - try to play with the `TOLERANCE`. Most likely you need to increase it (I don't know the exact value that is "good enough" for your particular application)

Comment: @YePhlcK these value is used for other expression and the final result is that for particular input combination, the results are more different.

Comment: also... in your particular code the correct statement would be `if( Math.abs(subtraction - completeExpression) > TOLERANCE )` since you are looking for "false" comparison.

Comment: @YePhIcK But the principal problem is that I have returned in C code completeExpression = 8.2779e-017
and subtraction = 5.5511e-017. This different values take me different results for the final elaborations.

Comment: @michele - this is a great point and the answer to it is to *be careful when doing floating-point math* as the result **may** depend on the sequence of your computations