# Numerical condition never true?

Tags: types, hlsl

### Overview

Last week I was creating a condition based pixel shader in `HLSL`. The goal was to color only pixels which met a specific condition. In my case the condition was based on *"time"*, which I say loosely because it's not what we consider traditional time. I was rendering a line in 3D space which is a trivial task. However, only a certain percentage of the line should be displayed based on the current user selected time.

I created a `Line` class and added a `SliderControl` to my form to allow the user to control the current point in time. This was simple enough to accomplish, as was setting up all of the underlying code.

---

### The Issue

While I was creating the underlying code, I made a simple mistake with my time types. In the constant buffer for the current time, I used `double`; within my `Vertex` structures (arbitrary definition and input, along with pixel shader input), I used `float`. This caused the condition in my pixel shader to always result in `false`. The reason for the difference was that the original data is `double` in type, but I ended up choosing `float` to match everything else in the code, plus there was some kind of issue with using `double` types in `HLSL`.

---

### The HLSL

The code was very straightforward:

```
cbuffer TimeBuffer : register(b4) {
    double CurrentTime;
}
struct VertexInput {
    float Time;
    //...
}
struct PixelInput {
    float Time;
    //...
}
float4 PSMain(PixelInput input) : SV_Target {
    float4 result = 0;
    if (input.Time < CurrentTime)
        result = input.Diffuse;

    return result;
}
```

---

### The Question

Why is the line never being rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is due to the type difference between the `cbuffer` and the `struct` for inputs. Simply make the types match:

```
cbuffer TimeBuffer : register(b4) {
    float CurrentTime;
}
struct VertexInput {
    float Time;
    //...
}
struct PixelInput {
    float Time;
    //...
}
float4 PSMain(PixelInput input) : SV_Target {
    float4 result = 0;
    if (input.Time < CurrentTime)
        result = input.Diffuse;

    return result;
}
```

Simply changing the initial assignment of `result` to `float4(0, 1, 0, 0)` or some other solid color will show that the line is indeed being rendered, but the condition is never evaluating as `true`.

---

A good thorough answer to why this is such an issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722293/why-comparing-double-and-float-leads-to-unexpected-result). I did not originally understand that this was an issue, because I assumed that `double` and `float` could be compared just like any other numeric type. I was wrong however, and as the post linked above stated:

> The important factors under consideration with float or double numbers are:
>
> **Precision:** The precision of a floating point number is how many digits it can represent without losing any information it contains.
>
> **Rounding:** There is a non-obvious differences between `binary` and `decimal (base 10)` numbers. Consider the fraction `1/10`. In `decimal`, this can be easily represented as `0.1`, and `0.1` can be thought of as an easily representable number. However, in binary, `0.1` is represented by the infinite sequence: `0.00011001100110011…`.

---

However, this also seems to matter with `int` and `float` instead of `double` and `float`.