# Float data type

Tags: c++

I am initializing a variable `a` of type `float` with value `1.2`.

If I print it on screen, it give me `1.2`, but when I check it with `if/else`, it does not run the `if` statement whose condition is `if(a == 1.2)`. Instead it runs the `else` part.

Can someone please help, I am still learning the basics.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float a = 1.2;
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<a<<endl;
    
    if (a == 1.2)
        cout<<"\n a is 1.2";
    else
        cout<<"\n a is not 1.2";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try if (a == 1.2f) instead of if (a == 1.2) That is use a constant of the type float instead of the type double.

Comment: `1.2` is a `double`, not a `float`. When you do `a == 1.2` it converts the value held by `a` to a `double` for the comparison. However a float can't store as precise a representation of `1.2` as double so the value you get when you convert back to `double` is slightly different from the original `1.2` double value.

Comment: Read this in its entirety  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Another good read: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3282436)

Comment: Floating point numbers are *not* exact (in general).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/)

Answer (score 0):

The it-statement is comparing a float to a double. `1.2` is a double and not a float.

Maybe this will give you some clarity: [Why comparing double and float leads to unexpected result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722293/why-comparing-double-and-float-leads-to-unexpected-result)

Hope this helps!