# Principle of java float number calculation error

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

In the first, I apologize for my poor English.

We all know Java float number calculation error. Such as follows:

```
System.out.println(0.0934 * 1000);
System.out.println(0.0935 * 1000);
System.out.println(0.0936 * 1000);
```

The result is

```
93.39999999999999
93.5
93.60000000000001
```

And we can use *BigDecimal* to resolve this problem.

**I want to know the principle of the error. What reason caused the problem.**

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Also: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Tons of similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461744/explain-this-floating-point-behavior
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581741/floating-point-error-in-representation

Comment: Mysticial, Greg Hewgill, leonbloy. Thanks a lot.