# Wrong result when comparing 0.55 and 0.55f

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

In C, `0.55 == 0.55f` is false while `0.5 == 0.5f` is true. Why is it different?

1. Comparing `0.55`:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main() {
       if (0.55 == 0.55f)
           printf("Hi");
       else
           printf("Hello");
   }
   ```

   Outputs `Hello`.
2. Comparing `0.5`:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main() {
       if (0.5 == 0.5f)
           printf("Hi");
       else
           printf("Hello");
   }
   ```

   Outputs `Hi`.

For both the code snippets, I expected `Hello`.
Why this difference?

Comment: Very related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: And for floating point values, you should almost never do direct comparison for equality. Use an *epsilon* to compare for closeness instead.

Comment: @George: Some programmer dude said "an epsilon", not a particular epsilon.

Comment: @Bathsheba Ah yep missed that. Though i'd argue it's confusing since C++ defines FLT_EPSILON and std::numeric_limits<float/double>::epsilon.

Comment: @George: As I'm sure you know, neither have any bearing at all on a choice of multiplicative, additive, or other type of *epsilon* one could consider using when comparing numerical quantities,

Comment: This question is very close (to the point I'd probably say duplicate) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691261/strange-output-when-comparing-same-float-values) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain this floating point behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461744/explain-this-floating-point-behavior)

Comment: [Can someone please explain me that in java why 0.6 is <0.6f but 0.7is >=0.7f](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16698198/995714), [Floating point comparison `a != 0.7`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6883306/995714), [strange output in comparison of float with float literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1839422/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strange output in comparison of float with float literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0.5` is a [*dyadic rational*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) and of an appropriate magnitude so `0.5` is exactly one-half either as a `float` or a `double`.

The same cannot be said for `0.55`. A `double` will store that number with no less precision than a `float`, and most likely more.

In both cases, the `float` is implicitly converted to a `double` prior to `==`, but by then any truncation has taken place.

Comment: SO only for 0.5 the if part will work and for all other comparisons the else part will work, isn't it??@Bathsheba

Comment: Other numbers will work too, e.g. small integers, rationals like 0.25, large integral powers of 2.

Comment: I did not down vote, but being a dyadic rational is a necessary but not sufficient condition that a number is exactly representable both as a `float` and a `double` (even assuming the C implementation uses base two). So this answer does not contain a full explanation.

Comment: I've addressed that by adding "of an appropriate magnitude".

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing two different types of values which are double and float. Think about the limitations of size with inexact numbers.

### Exact values (decimal)

A -> 1/2 with 5 decimals is 0.5000

B -> 1/2 with 10 decimals is 0.5000000000

A == B will always return true

### Inexact values (decimal)

A -> 1/3 with 5 decimals is 0.33333

B -> 1/3 with 10 decimals is 0.3333333333

A == B -> will always return false because they aren't the same.

Similarly, 0.55 cannot be represented exactly in binary but 0.5 can be.

The binary representation of 0.55d -> 0.10001100110011001101...

So they will not be equal

The binary representation of 0.5d -> 0.1

So they will be equal

Hope It clears your doubt