# Regarding floats and comparison operator in C

Tags: c, floating-point

```
int main()
{
    float lfResult = 19.893196;
    if(lfResult == 19.893196)
        printf("Works");
    else
        printf("does not work");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output: does not work

Why does the `if` condition fail?

Comment: You might like this blog post: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparision-of-float-with-float-literal

Answer (score 8):

In C floating constants have the type `double`. Try:

```
float lfResult = 19.893196f;
if(lfResult == 19.893196f)
                        ^
```

Thus the constant `19.893196` has more precision than `lfResult`.

> 6.4.4.2 - 4
>
> **An unsufﬁxed ﬂoating constant has type double**. If sufﬁxed by the
>   letter f or F, it has type float. If sufﬁxed by the letter l or L, it
>   has type long double.

Answer (score 1):

your literal is a double, casted to float in assignement.

try:

```
if(lfResult == 19.893196F)
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In if condition, 19.893196 can be taken as double. So the if condition fails.

You should try like following way.

```
if(lfResult == 19.893196f)
```

I think it will be helpful to you.