# C++ float vs double cout setprecision oddities(newbie)

Tags: c++, math, precision, floating-accuracy

Can anyone explain why these two variable of the same value can output different values when i use setprecision()?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    float a=98.765;
    double b = 98.765;
    //std::cout<<std::setprecision(2)<<a<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::fixed;
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(2)<<a<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(2)<<b<<std::endl;
}
```

The output for a will be 98.76 while the output for b will be 98.77.

Comment: You start from a wrong assumption, _"why these two variable of the same value_": they don't have the same value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double

Comment: Protip:  don't use float unless you have to.  Complete pain in the ass.

Comment: @zzxyz: float or double? Both are justified, except when calculating monetary units, which are integral.

Comment: @Nipun  Em I think after I call the std::fixed, all of the commands I gave below follow the fixed rule?

Comment: @zzxyz Ok noted.

Comment: float - The loss of precision that occurs can be relatively large, in addition to being non-intuitive, particularly in terms of base-10 numbers and rounding.  Certainly they are necessary for certain applications, but definitely to be avoided imo.

Comment: Also see [strange output in comparison of float with float literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those variables *don't* have the same value. When you shoehorn the literal `double` of `98.765` into the float, it has to do a best fit, and some precision is lost.

You can see this quite easily if you change the precision to 50, you'll also see that not even the double can represent that value exactly:

```
98.76499938964843750000000000000000000000000000000000
98.76500000000000056843418860808014869689941406250000
```

However, the important thing is that the former `float` variable will round down, the latter `double` will round up.

See also the [IEEE754 online converter](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=057056046055054053).