# Negative zero isn't equal to positive zero

Tags: c

so i am having this strange problem here and I don't know what to do.

so in the following I am posting an excerpt of my code:

```
printf("%lf , %lf \n", cGrid_Y,sideLength);

printf("%lf <= %lf\n", Point_Y, cGrid_Y+sideLength);

bool x = (Point_Y <= (sideLength + cGrid_Y) );
printf("%s \n", x ? "true" : "false");
```

cGrid_Y and sideLength are doubles. And I am getting this output:

```
-12.800000 , 12.800000 
0.000000 <= -0.000000
false
```

So my question is, why I am not getting a true ?

Comment: Try printing with `%g`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strange output in comparison of float with float literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal)

Comment: Try printing the value this way: printf("%le <= %le\n", Point_Y, cGrid_Y+sideLength); You may not be seeing a very small value.

Comment: Your question was put on hold because you didn't provide enough information for us to be sure what the problem is. We don't know the values of `cGrid_Y` and `sideLength` or how they were set. Read this: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@edit I wrote a stupid mistaken thing: I thought that negative zero doesn't equal positive zero, whereas after reading it all properly -0 equals +0.

The source of your problem: you are trying to test whether two doubles are equal, and this is a terrible idea, due to the imprecision of floating point representation. Note the common example: 0.1 + 0.2 does NOT equal 0.3:

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

https://www.quora.com/Why-is-0-1+0-2-not-equal-to-0-3-in-most-programming-languages

You cannot represent 12.8 in binary without losing a part of the imformation, due to the fundamental nature of how this number is stored in the computer's memory.

The same way you can't represent 1/7 in our "normal" decimal representation of numbers with a finite amount of digits.

Comment: In IEEE754 FP there's a 0 and a -0, but they do compare equal.

Comment: this isn't correct. `-0.0` is equal to `0.0`

Comment: Thank you for adding this information, it was an absurdly stupid mistake on my part. At least I learned something too.

Comment: but thank you for the links, they helped me understanding this problem!

Answer (score 6):

This is not a problem with negative zeros. `0.0 <= -0.0` is true. The problem is that your values are not actually zero or negative zero but some very small value that's being rounded to 0 for presentation when you ask `printf` to show it rounded to 6 decimal places. Either print with `%e` or `%g` (which will use exponential notation to show a better approximation) or `%.1100f` which is sufficient precision to show the exact value of any `double`.

Comment: Yes i have done this an they are actually not equal to zero. I have now rounded them to their e^-10 decimal space. Now it is working. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is, why I am not getting a true ?

Are you sure that `Point_Y == 0.0`? Same for the sum of `sideLength + cGrid_Y`?
Check your assumptions:

```
printf("Point_Y is zero: %d\n", Point_Y == 0.0);
printf("`sideLength + cGrid_Y` is zero: %d\n", (sideLength + cGrid_Y) == 0.0);
```

The reason you got confused is because by default printf's [floats/doubles are't printed to full precision](https://ideone.com/YtJRwj).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double x = 0.0000001;
  printf("x: %f\n", x);
}
```

outputs: `x: 0.000000`