# Floating point comparision

Tags: c, if-statement, floating-point, double, single-precision

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float f; 
    f = 0.4;
    if(f<0.4)
       printf("It is less");
    if(f>0.4)
       printf("It is greater");
    if(f==0.4)
       printf("It is equal");
}
```

I am not able to get why the output is showing "It is greater".

I get that 0.4 converted to binary representation is 0x3ECCCCCD, which is 4.000000059604644775390625E-1. 
The doubt is if f stores this rounded value, why 0.4 in the comparison is exact. If both f and 0.4 gets rounded, the output should have been "It is equal".

I tried with f = 0.5, it is showing "It is equal".

While f=0.9, it is showing "It is less".

*Please take note that there is no arithmetic at all.*

Comment: The value `0.4` in your comparison is a *`double`*.

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Comment: Also please read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Look at this https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @gsamaras: He doesn't do any arithmetic though, so that's not quite a good dupe-target.

Comment: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal

Answer (score 4):

While `f` is a `float`, all your literals are `double`.

If  you ask nicely, [the compiler will even warn you about the assignment](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b483af9ae15bf181):

> warning: conversion from 'double' to 'float' changes value from '4.0000000000000002e-1' to '4.00000006e-1f' [-Wfloat-conversion]

Unfortunately, it cannot warn about the comparison, because simply widening the smaller type is nearly always what you want, and was thus codified.

Anyway, floating-point math is dangerous and surprising for the uninitiated:
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: What would happen if OP had `f = 0.4f` in assignment, and `if(f<0.4)` in comparison? It would be a failure of the same type, but would the compiler emit any warning then? (I suspect not; cannot check)

Comment: @anatolyg Yes, there are limitations to automatic checking: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c359e04ea5623d9c