# NSNumber's stringValue print other strings what we don't want

Tags: nsnumber

> (lldb) po [@(70.033) stringValue]
>   70.033
>   (lldb) po [@(80.138) stringValue]
>   80.13800000000001
>   (lldb) po [@(70.138) stringValue]
>   70.13800000000001
>   (lldb) po [@(100.01) stringValue]
>   100.01
>   (lldb) po [@(90.03) stringValue]
>   90.03
>   (lldb) po [@(90.01) stringValue]
>   90.01000000000001
>   (lldb) po [@(900.01) stringValue]
>   900.01
>   (lldb) po [@(100.01) stringValue]
>   100.01
>   (lldb) po [@(80.01) stringValue]
>   80.01000000000001

Is this a bug form the NSNumber? Or a mistake with my Mac?

Comment: Is *what* a bug or a mistake? The output you show seems to be a series of numbers printed in the `lldb` debugger, so it's hard to understand which strings you do want and which you don't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I don't think so, and I also want to confirm that : Is @(90.01)  == [NSNumber numberWithFloat:90.01]; ?
here is code : 
 {  NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:90.01];
//             NSNumber *num = @(90.01);
             NSString *str = [num stringValue];
             NSLog(@"str - %@", str);
             str - 90.01
}

{
//             NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:90.01];
             NSNumber *num = @(90.01);
             NSString *str = [num stringValue];
             NSLog(@"str - %@", str);
              str - 90.01000000000001    <- that I don't want
}

Comment: "90.01000000000001 <- that I don't want" - please read the answer I linked to, it explains why this happens and why your expectation is flawed. If you want to avoid these kinds of things, use `NSDecimalNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a bug. It is just the standard issue with the internal representation of numbers. 
So (in Swift):

```
var a = 0.15 + 0.15
var b = 0.1 + 0.2
print (a == b) // can be false!
print (a >= b) // can also be false!

var c = 80.138
print(c) // 80.138
print (c - 80.0 - 0.138) // 5.218048215738236e-15
```

There are many people observing this "strang" behaviour, in almost any programming language. Just check some web sites like stackoverflow.com:

[strange output in comparison of float with float literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal)

or, with nice images:

https://bitbashing.io/comparing-floats.html