# Avoid ValueError outside a while loop?

Tags: python, loops, try-catch

In the second line, I am trying to make it not crash if a string is entered but can't find a way to use an exception or something similar. In the while loop it works normally as the exception deals with this case.

```
number = 0 #this to be removed
number = (float(input('pick a number'))) #I want to make this not crash if a string is entered.
while number not in [100, 200, 3232]:
    try:
        print('wrong number ')
        number = (float(input('pick a number;'))) #Here it does not crash if a string is entered which is fine
    except ValueError:
        print("retry")
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` followed by a variable condition often ends up with bugs/repeating code => bad maintenability.

Use a `while True` condition to avoid repeating your code, then break out the loop when it's valid.

```
while True:
    try:
        number = float(input('pick a number;'))
        if number in [100, 200, 3232]:
           break
        print("wrong number")
    except ValueError:
        print("illegal number, retry")
```

note: be careful with float equality in the general case (see also [strange output in comparison of float with float literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken))

Comment: please answer the question when you have the time. What is the correct approach if the list also had float numbers?

Comment: see my edit to understand potential issues with floats

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a function to take input:

```
def get_input():
    while True:
        a = input("Pick a number: ")
        try:
            return float(a)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: `"5.0".isnumeric()` is False.

Comment: It wasn't provided what input he's expecting.