# Large number store in float type in C

Tags: c

The problem I got is if I assign a large number to a float type, for example, `float f = 1.0e20` then I print it to the screen with `printf("f = %f\n",f)`, then on the screen it will be `f = 100000002004087730000.000000`. Could anyone tell me why the number display is not `100000000000000000000.000000`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: precision.......Question asked many times and in many forms on SO

Comment: http://web.cse.msu.edu/~cse320/Documents/FloatingPoint.pdf

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839225/float-addition-promoted-to-double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you are using has no exact representation in the type you are storing it. As a result, the answers will never be exactly right.

By analogy, consider a computer that used 6 decimal digits. The best you can do for `1/3` is `.333333` But then `3 * (1/3) != 1`. Oh well.

And what about `2/3`? If you use `.666667` then `2/3 != 2 * (1/3)`. If you use `.666666` then `1/3 + 2/3 != 1`. Oh well.

That's just the way it is with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing, floating point variables are represented as a **aproximation** of a fixed number which is later scaled with an exponent. In your case, the number is too big to being stored in a accurate way. Try using a `double` instead and printing it out with `%lf`. It'll be more accurate, although don't expect a real equality.

Comment: And of course, try to search by your own the answer before asking.

Comment: To print `double`s, use `%f`, the `l` modifier has no effect before an `f` conversion specifier.